# How to use both Devise and Doorkeeper gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, oauth-2.0

I am building a web app (with an API too) that is using Devise gem for authentication and I also use Doorkeeper gem for authentication for the API part.

Problem is now that when I go to the URL for receiving the Oauth2 code (and login) I am redirected to the web app and not the client callback URL.

What I need to do is redirect to the web app when signing in normally and to the callback URL when using Oauth.

How can I do this? I am overwriting the Devise sessions controller but I do not know what to put into it.

This is my code:

```
def new
    session[:return_to] = params[:return_to] if params[:return_to]
    resource = build_resource
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
  end

  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    if session[:return_to]
      redirect_to session[:return_to]
      session[:return_to] = nil
    else
      respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    end
  end
```

Problem is that Devise seems to ignore my redirect logic.

Please advice further.

Answer (score 12):

Assuming your resource is `user`  add `session[:user_return_to] = request.fullpath` to resource_owner_authenticator block

Example:

```
resource_owner_authenticator do
  #raise "Please configure doorkeeper resource_owner_authenticator block located in #{__FILE__}"
  # Put your resource owner authentication logic here.
  # Example implementation:
  session[:user_return_to] = request.fullpath
  current_user || redirect_to(login_url)
end
```

Comment: `login_url` might be `new_user_session_url`

Comment: this gave me an circular redirection... See my answer on how I did solve it.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me, in ApplicationController (that Devise's controllers inherit from):

```
def store_location
  # store last url as long as it isn't a /users path
  session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath unless request.fullpath =~ /\/users/
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(_resource)
  session[:previous_url] || root_path
end
```

And in the Doorkeeper initializer:

```
resource_owner_authenticator do
  if user_signed_in?
    current_user
  else
    session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath unless request.fullpath =~ /\/users/
    redirect_to(new_user_session_path)
  end
```

end

The idea is to remember the path you came from in a session cookie and then let Devise redirect there when it calls its own `after_sign_in_path_for` callback.

[Documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/Helpers:after_sign_in_path_for) pointed out the `resource_return_to` session key, but this worked for me so I didn't examine anymore.

Comment: It was maybe due to my implementation of devise with u2f but my session[:previous_url] was empty in after_sign_in_path_for so I used a cookie instead of session

Comment: @phyzalis I'm facing a similar issue, how did you solve it with cookies?

Comment: I was able to get around it by using super in `after_sign_in_path_for`, 
`session[:previous_url] || super`

Comment: Sorry, it's been a long time and I don't remind how I managed this